# Duda sobre como como limpiar los datos parseados de una pagina web

Tags: html, xml, beautifulsoup

estoy haciendo un codigo en el que tengo que extraer el concello y su identificador asociado de la siguiente pagina web:https://irdgcdinfo.data.blog/ayuntamientos/, usando la libreria BeautifulSoup. De momento al ejecutar mi programa me devuelve esto:

```
 <tr><th>15001</th><th>Abegondo</th></tr>   # concello = Abegondo, ID: 150001
 <tr><th>15002</th><th>Ames</th></tr>
 <tr><th>15003</th><th>Aranga</th></tr>
 <tr><th>15004</th><th>Ares</th></tr>
 <tr><th>15005</th><th>Arteixo</th></tr>
 ....
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo limpiar esos datos para que solo me devuelva concello - ID. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que tenes la tabla en una variable `tabla` lo podes hacer así:

```py
import bs4

html = """
    <tr>
        <th>15001</th>
        <th>Abegondo</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>15002</th>
        <th>Ames</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>15003</th>
        <th>Aranga</th>
    </tr>
"""

tabla = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tr_tag in tabla.find_all("tr"):
    concello_tag, id_tag = tr_tag.find_all("th")
    print(f"Concello: {concello_tag.text}, ID: {id_tag.text}")
```